# Trouble getting related fields in ForeignKeys to show in Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm working in Django 2.2 trying to build a view for a database that compiles everything for a specific company (locations of all of their stores and notes on the companies) into a single view. I've tried methods in several different answers, but still cannot seem to get data from related foreign keys to show in the template.

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    official_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    corporate_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    corporate_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Stores(models.Model):
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    store_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=store_types)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("store-detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

class notes(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

class Country(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=countries,primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-country"]
        db_table = 'country'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country
```

views.py

```
class CompanyOverView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = "company-overview.html"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    query_pk_and_slug = True
    pk_url_kwarg = "company.name"
```

template

```
<div align="center">
<p>{{ object.name }}<br>({{ object.official_name }})</p>
<p>{{ object.corporate_address1 }}<br>{{ object.corporate_address2 }}<br>
   {{ object.city }}<br>{{ object.state_province }}<br>
   {{ object.country }}</p>
</div>
<p>List of Stores</p>
<p>
{% for instance in object_list %}
    {{ instance.company.stores.store_name }}
    {{ instance.company.stores.store_address1 }}
    {{ instance.company.stores.store_address2 }}
    {{ instance.company.stores.city }}
    {{ instance.company.stores.state_province }}
    {{ instance.company.stores.country }}
{% endfor %}
</p>
<p>Notes</p>
<p>
{% for instance in object_list %}
    {{ instance.company.notes.title }}
    {{ instance.company.notes.posted }}
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

With the above code, the only thing that appears when you enter in the company's name is everything at the top (e.g."object.name" appears on the page as "Acme Corporation"). Nothing in the for loop appears on the web page.

Looking at the documentation, object_list is the default name for context unless specified. I have tried different combinations such as "for store_name in company.store_set.all" and other combinations I found in other posts, but none have worked. I've combed the documentation for everything related to foreign keys, but can't find a solution that works.

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `object_list` is the default context name in a ListView. But you have a DetailView, and you already know what the default context name is for those because you're already using it: `object`. You just need to iterate over the reverse relation from there:

```
{% for store in object.stores_set.all %}
    {{ store.store_name }}
    {{ store.store_address1 }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I was looking at ListView vs DetailView, but couldn't figure it out. It worked like a charm.